# How to make mysql query ignore value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query and the values from $B and $C is from dropdown menu, how can i add a value that is ignored by this query or how can i make this query igonre a constant value? In other words i need a value that will throw out all the results, like B='$B' and C='$C' didnt exist in this query

```
 select * from TABLE where A like '%$name%' AND B='$B' AND C='$C'
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your `PHP`?

Comment: remove `AND B='$B' AND C='$C'` from the query and it should work ;)
I think it's much better, if you do it in PHP

Comment: but i need them to filter only if for example value="blank" is select the query should ignore those two ANDs

Comment: Is it a problem to check in PHP if the value is blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
  A like '%$name%' AND
  ((B='$B' AND C='$C') OR '$B'='all_values')
```

If you se the value of $B to `'all_values'`, this query will return all rows that satisfy the first condition (`A LIKE '%$name%'`) ignoring the second one (`B='$B' AND C='$C'`) because of the OR.